# Output JS file of Webpack is not accessible in subdirectories

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am generating a output JS file named `transformed.js` through webpack. But there is a problem with the way it is injecting it in html file. In HTML file, it is not including a slash in front of this file. Due to which if I move to any subdirectory then browser fails to find `transformed.js` because it starts looking for this file in that subdirectory. I am attaching screenshot of error for better clarification

[image]

It is happening because in HTML file it is getting injected like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="transformed.js"></script>
```

But ideally it should be getting injected like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/transformed.js"></script>
```

My Webpack configfuration is this

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/app/index.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            { 
                test: /\.css$/, 
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'react-svg'
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, 
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=88192'
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: __dirname + '/build'
    },  
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting publicPath:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
    filename: 'transformed.js',
    publicPath: '/'
}
```